# Check if a font is installed

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, typekit

I'm using Typekit for Proxima Nova and wondered if there is a Javascript or jQuery plugin for checking if somebody has Proxima Nova installed?

If so, I'd like to use that and then use jQuery to remove the Typekit loading class to make the page load faster.

Possible?

Answer (score 2):

It is highly unlikely that any of your visitors will have this font installed since it doesn't come as part of any standard OS installation.

Based on the link below, I don't believe that it is part of the Adobe suite either, which makes the possibility of someone having it even slimmer.

http://techinch.com/2010/05/21/what-fonts-are-included-with-photoshop-cs4-cs5-and-elements-8/

So the amount of time that you would spend in trying to create this elaborate check will be a waste since most people will still end up getting it from typekit.

Comment: But since this site I'm creating is for designers, they've most probably got Proxima Nova installed.

Comment: Actually, since they are designers, they are probably using Adobe products. Unless something has changed in cs5 - 6, adobe products do not ship with this font. This means that they actually will probably not have this font installed.

Comment: I know, I just wanted to check if somebody has font installed, if so, they've bought the font or have it cached

Comment: Sorry Jamie, I might be missing something from your overall intent. Josh Mein posted a possible answer to your question but ultimately, it will be a wasted effort since most people will still end up loading it from typekit.

Answer (score 1):

[how-to-detect-if-a-font-is-installed-only-using-javascript](http://remysharp.com/2008/07/08/how-to-detect-if-a-font-is-installed-only-using-javascript/) is an interesting tutorial on how to do check if a font is installed. There are several potential issues mentioned within the tutorial, but you can decide whether it is worthy of your time or not.